# How do I create a function so that it has the limits I want?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I am in high school, working on using calculus to graph and find the volume of my hand. To do this more accurately, I have broken down the shape of my hand into fragments that can be represented as a function a bit easier. I'm starting off with finding a function for the tips of my fingers, because that seemed simple enough, and I got to this (vertex form): $$f(x)=-0.75(x+2.25)^2+16$$

To get a better picture (pun intended, i'm **suffering**) this is what it looks like on desmos: [finger tip function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D8OK.jpg). I want to set limits so that the function does not exist outside of the points (-1, 14.8) and (-3.81, 14.8). I don't even know how to THINK about solving this. Is there some way I should edit my function so that those limits exist? When I try setting limits for $-x^2$ on desmos, I can get the shape of the parabola right but not the placement of it where I need it to be. In any case, I just need those limits to exist for my function. If your answer could also help me to do this for the three other functions I'll have to do for the rest of my finger tips by offering some general steps, that would be great.

Comment: You can use restrictions for your graph. In your case, you can add `{-3.81 <= x <= -1.14}` after the function definition.

Comment: FYI - estimating the volumes of irregularly shaped objects is a need that occurs all the time. The easiest general method is to plot a huge number of surface points to form a triangulation of the surface - approximating the shape with small triangles. Then you choose some interior point and form tetrahedra with that point as the fourth vertex. Sum the volumes of all the tetrahedra to estimate the volume of the solid. With careful treatment and oriented volumes you can even handle non-convex shapes this way. The estimation improves, the smaller the triangles are.